# SQL query works on phpMyAdmin but not in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have this query

```sql
SELECT
    arl_kind,
    IF (tof_art_lookup.arl_kind = 2, tof_suppliers.sup_brand, tof_brands.bra_brand) AS brand,
    arl_display_nr
FROM
    tof_art_lookup
LEFT JOIN
    tof_brands
ON
    bra_id = arl_bra_id
INNER JOIN
    tof_articles
ON
    tof_articles.art_id = tof_art_lookup.arl_art_id
INNER JOIN
    tof_suppliers
ON
    tof_suppliers.sup_id = tof_articles.art_sup_id
WHERE
    arl_art_id = @art_id
AND arl_kind IN (3)
ORDER BY
    arl_kind,
    bra_brand,
    arl_display_nr limit 100;
```

when I execute this on phpmyadmin or in any software that has sql comand capabilities everything works and the output is as i should.

The problem appears when I try to insert this in codeigniter, and my main probles is with the if statement, I tried to insert it like this

```php
return $query = $this->db
    ->SELECT('
        arl_kind,
        IF (tof_art_lookup.arl_kind = 2, tof_suppliers.sup_brand, tof_brands.bra_brand) AS brand,
        arl_display_nr
    FROM
        tof_art_lookup
    LEFT JOIN
        tof_brands
    ON
        bra_id = arl_bra_id
    INNER JOIN
        tof_articles
    ON
        tof_articles.art_id = tof_art_lookup.arl_art_id
    INNER JOIN
        tof_suppliers
    ON
        tof_suppliers.sup_id = tof_articles.art_sup_id
    WHERE
        arl_art_id = @art_id
    AND arl_kind IN (3)
    ORDER BY
        arl_kind,
        bra_brand,
        arl_display_nr limit 100')
        ->get();
```

and second option like that

```php
return $query = $this->db
    ->select('ARL_KIND, IF (tof_art_lookup.arl_kind = 2, tof_suppliers.sup_brand, tof_brands.bra_brand) AS brand,ARL_DISPLAY_NR')
    ->from('tof_art_lookup')
    ->join('tof_brands','bra_id = arl_bra_id','LEFT')
    ->join('tof_articles','tof_articles.art_id = tof_art_lookup.arl_art_id','INNER')
    ->join('tof_suppliers','tof_suppliers.sup_id = tof_articles.art_sup_id','INNER')
    ->where('ARL_ART_ID',$id)
    ->where_in('ARL_KIND',array('3'))
    //->where('A.ARL_DISPLAY','0')
    ->group_by('arl_kind','bra_brand','arl_display_nr')
    ->get();
```

both of them work but partialy without the second select option the one with the if.

Can anyone help me to fix this.

Comment: It's better to use `query()` method in this case, take a look here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code should look like this

```
return $query = $this->db
        ->select('arl_kind, IF(tof_art_lookup.arl_kind = 2, tof_suppliers.sup_brand, tof_brands.bra_brand) AS brand,ARL_DISPLAY_NR', FALSE)
        ->from('tof_art_lookup')
        ->join('tof_brands', 'bra_id = arl_bra_id', 'LEFT')
        ->join('tof_articles', 'tof_articles.art_id  = tof_art_lookup.arl_art_id', 'INNER')
        ->join('tof_suppliers','tof_suppliers.sup_id = tof_articles.art_sup_id', 'INNER')
        ->where('arl_art_id', $id)
        ->where_in('arl_kind', array('3'))
        ->order_by('arl_kind','bra_brand','arl_display_nr')
        ->limit(100)
        ->get();
```

*Note: second parameter of `select()` method is set to `FALSE` and `order_by()` is used instead of `group_by()` as in your original query.*

Comment: YES, it works, I thought that I should have that statement only in if function. Thank You. The problem with this is that it shows only one result, I should get all the answears for that id.

Comment: Great! It looks like you didn't change `group_by()` to `order_by` did you?

Comment: I change it, but I see after a refresh it works as it should. Great. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 $query_string = "SELECT
        arl_kind,
        IF (tof_art_lookup.arl_kind = 2, tof_suppliers.sup_brand, tof_brands.bra_brand) AS brand,
        arl_display_nr
    FROM
        tof_art_lookup
    LEFT JOIN
        tof_brands
    ON
        bra_id = arl_bra_id
    INNER JOIN
        tof_articles
    ON
        tof_articles.art_id = tof_art_lookup.arl_art_id
    INNER JOIN
        tof_suppliers
    ON
        tof_suppliers.sup_id = tof_articles.art_sup_id
    WHERE
        arl_art_id = @art_id
    AND arl_kind IN (3)
    ORDER BY
        arl_kind,
        bra_brand,
        arl_display_nr limit 100";



$query=$this->db->query($query_string);
if ($query->num_rows () > 0) {
    return $query->result_array ();
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```